# How to set style on custom view

Tags: android, android-layout

If I subclass a widget, e.g. EditText, how can I apply a style on it?

E.g. if I have a plain EditText in my application I can do the following in the style.xml and change the appearence of all instances of EditText:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/Edit</item>
</style>


<style name="Edit" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit</item>
</style>
```

But, if I have subclassed the EditText and have a class MyEditText, how can I set the style to all instances of MyEditText? E.g.:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="MyEditText">@style/Edit</item>
</style>
```

**EDIT:** *Clarification*

I am **not** trying to add new attributes which I then would be able to use for various things.

I am looking for a way to simply state that I want all widgets of type *MyEditText* to have the the default appearande defined by style *@style/Edit* in the scope of the application. In other words, just as you can set the default appearance of the EditText in a theme, how can you set a default appearance of MyEditText in the same way?

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to use the constructor that takes in an AttributeSet parameter in your custom view subclass. Then you declare your styles in an XML file and apply them like you normally would. See the [developer page about Creating a Custom View Class here](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html). Good luck!

```
class CustomView extends View {
public CustomView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(ctx, attrs);
}
}
```

In your attrs.xml(or whatever name) is where you define your styleable attributes

```
<resources>;
   <declare-styleable name="CustomView">
   <attr name="showText" format="boolean" />
   <attr name="labelPosition" format="enum">
       <enum name="left" value="0"/>
       <enum name="right" value="1"/>
   </attr>
```

In your xml you include these attributes like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.customviews">
 <com.example.customviews.CustomView
 custom:showText="true"
 custom:labelPosition="left" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This, although very useful, does not answer my question. I'll try to clarify the question.